# Calculating unit vectors B , T , N a (probably ellipse like) curve

Tags: curves, elliptic-curves, tangent-line, frenet-frame

$$r(t) = a\cos(t)i+b\sin(t)j+ctk$$
So this is the equation of a curve for which I've had trouble calculating it's unit vectors, especially
$B$ and $N$.

I know that $T = v/|v|$ and that also $B = v × a / |v \times a|$, but when it comes to calculating $N= (dT/dt)/(|dT/dt|)$ it becomes impossible for me to calcite the dervative of $T$ with respect to $t$.

Comment: To find $N$ you could use $$N=\frac{v\times(a\times v)}{|v||a\times v|}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> If it matters, your curve is an _elliptic helix_.

Comment: Thank you Andrew!